# Check_birthday program

Tags: shell, unix

I'm making check_birthday through Unix.
But I have a problem in `if` statement.

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 T1=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
  3 if ["$T1" = "2021-05-19"]; then
  4         echo Today is $T1. Happy Birthday!
  5 else
  6         echo Today is $T1. Not your Birthday.
  7 fi
  8
```

I have a question about if `["$T1" = "2021-05-19"]`. because results said `"Line 3: [2021-05-19: Command not found"`
Any reply will be thankful. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, you need a space after `[`, as in:

```
 if [ "$T1" = "2021-05-19" ]; then
```

This is because `[` is actually a Bash command!

```
$ type -a [
    [ is a shell builtin
```

In Bash, `[` is a program that evaluates its contents, and stops evaluating once it sees `]`. When you do `["$T1"` Bash things you're trying to run a program called (after expansion) `[2021-05-18` which doesn't exist.

This is part of why Bash is such a terrible language.

Comment: Well... `[ ... ]` is actually an alias for `test`. The rest of your answer is fine, but the last sentence significantly detracts from an an otherwise good answer. Generally you want to omit opinions as others may have an entirely different view. If you can fix that I can happily vote for your answer.

Comment: @Luna if this answer, or someone else, answered your question, make sure to check the empty checkmark next to the answer, to help others find it and to give people fake internet points.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've worked with arrays in Bash, that last sentence isn't an opinion :P